# Typescript install error Permission

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

While trying to install typescript, I get a permission and path error. Can someone assists me with installing typescript correctly?   [Typescript install error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oiZq1.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use "`sudo npm install -g typescript`".